# Properly design of a CosmosDB

Tags: database-design, azure-cosmosdb

I have been having conversations with some people of my team in relation with tech elements of how to design properly a Cosmos DB. In terms of Azure, we are already using Azure Storage (blobs), and as you know you are able to append metadata and tags to the blob in order to manage additional information in relation with the object. So, one of my colleagues suggested to use the same approach as the Blobs, and append metadata or tags to the documents stored in the Collections in Cosmos DB. I am not sure if this is even possible, but if it is, i don't see any additional value on mapping this information as metadata instead of properties of the document.

Could you please share you opinion in relation with this? And also if you have any recommendations to consider in the design of the DB, i would appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just for your referring.

Based on your description, you didn't mention what is the type of your metadata which stored in Blob Storage. If you could convert them into `json` file, you could import them via [Cosmos DB Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) directly. Or you could copy your data into cosmos db via [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db).

> i don't see any additional value on mapping this information as
>   metadata instead of properties of the document.

1.From an operational point of view, blob storage needs to be accessed entirely and is less convenient to operate than document DB.

2.From a usability point of view, blob storage may perform better than document db in concurrent situations. Of course, performance is affected by many factors.

3.In terms of price, blob storage is cheaper than document db for large amounts of data.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Jay, sorry but i think potentially my question was not clear. I am not trying to do a comparison in terms of blob storage or cosmos Db in order to decide which one to use, even because it is two really different systems. I am asking if it makes any sense to manage information via metadata or tags on a Cosmos DB, instead of using properties in the document stored in a given collection in the cosmos db.